# Compare 2 columns in 2 files and print the soustraction result

Tags: database, file, awk, compare, tablespace

I'm trying to compare tablespaces sizes between 2 databases. I already extracted the needed field to compare as above:

**STAT-TBS-DB-SOURCE.lst: (column 1 : TBS Name, column 2 : real size)**

```
TBS001 12
TBS002 50
TBS003 20
TBS004 45
```

**STAT-TBS-DBTARGET.lst (column1:TBS Name, column 2 :max size)**

```
TBS001 10
TBS002 50
TBS003 20
TBS004 40
```

I need to compare the second columns (c1,c2) of the 2 files (f1,f2), if `f2.c2<f1.c2` then print `increase Tablespace f1.c1 by ( f1.c2 - f2.c2) MB`.

What solution have you for me?

I tried with awk but I cannot get the value of the f1.c2.

Thanks

Comment: FYI `What solution have you for me?` would generally be considered rude in English. You might want to say something like `Could you please help me solve my problem?` in future.

Comment: Hi Kent, Thank you! my english is not very good, sorry for the missunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a && $2<a[$1]{
       printf "increase Tablespace %s by %d MB\n",$1,(a[$1]-$2)}' f f2 
increase Tablespace TBS001 by 2 MB
increase Tablespace TBS004 by 5 MB
```

Comment: thanks 
it works 
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a && $2<a[$1]{ print "alter database datafile '\''" $3  "'\'' resize "(a[$1])"M;"}' source target